# Windows event log export - how to get general description?

Tags: windows, windows-event-log, export

I am exporting windows Application event logs to XML from one of my servers for offline analysis. I am able to do this...but when I do, I lose the "General" description information. Here is an example event. In the windows event log viewer, it displays the following as a general description:

> Application 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mountain Duck\Mountain Duck.exe'
>   (pid 2940) cannot be restarted - Application SID does not match
>   Conductor SID..

However when I export to XML, this is all I get:

```
<Event xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'>
    <System>
        <Provider Name='Microsoft-Windows-RestartManager' Guid='{0888E5EF-9B98-4695-979D-E92CE4247224}'/>
        <EventID>10010</EventID>
        <Version>0</Version>
        <Level>3</Level>
        <Task>0</Task>
        <Opcode>0</Opcode>
        <Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords>
        <TimeCreated SystemTime='2016-04-07T20:00:10.245609600Z'/>
        <EventRecordID>6889</EventRecordID>
        <Correlation/>
        <Execution ProcessID='3868' ThreadID='4016'/>
        <Channel>Application</Channel>
        <Computer>WIN-8S18ONBFAEP</Computer>
        <Security UserID='S-1-5-21-3589301003-3870519012-1491501718-500'/>
    </System>
    <UserData>
        <RmUnsupportedRestartEvent xmlns='http://www.microsoft.com/2005/08/Windows/Reliability/RestartManager/'>
        <RmSessionId>0</RmSessionId>
        <Pid>2940</Pid>
        <FullPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Mountain Duck\Mountain Duck.exe</FullPath>
        <DisplayName>Mountain Duck</DisplayName>
        <AppVersion>0</AppVersion>
        <AppType>0</AppType>
        <TSSessionId>2</TSSessionId>
        <Status>67108865</Status>
        <Reason>1</Reason>
        </RmUnsupportedRestartEvent>
    </UserData>
</Event>
```

Is there any way to include the descriptive text when saving event logs? I've tried every search I can think of, and can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Powershell

```
Get-EventLog -LogName System -Newest 100 | select * | Export-Clixml log.xml
```